# Convert binary image to a Gussian points

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution

I have a binary image **A** that contains some white points. Now I want an image **B** where for every white point in **A** the intensity is spread to its neighbors so that these points have a value of 1 and the value decrease around it. So that the final image **B** has values range of [0 1] where 1 happens at the my white points.

My approach:

I convolved the image with Gaussian function using this code:

```
x=-ceil(siz/2):ceil(siz/2);
H = exp(-(x.^2/(2*sigma^2)));
H = H/sum(H(:));%normalize the kernel
Hx=reshape(H,[length(H) 1]);
Hy=reshape(H,[1 length(H)]);
I=imfilter(imfilter(I,Hx, 'same' ,'replicate'),Hy, 'same' ,'replicate');
```

Problem:
As I do this to the whole image, I face a problem when I have two successive white neighbors, the convolution at these points has a high value, thus , when normalizing **B** the maximum happens at this location, and my original white points has a values less than 1.

Is there any way where I can spread the intensity individually (treat each point as a source regardless of its neighbors) and the final image is the maximum of this operations ,so that at the location of 2 white points, the two points have values of 1 and their neighbors have  maximum of the 2 Gaussians ??[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a hard cap.

Either save the locations of the white points before the convolution or find the location of all points > 1 and set them to 1 like this:

```
B(B>1) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Muller I can deal with this now ,but still can't treat each pixel alone. The final image has a lot of white batches :)